# Trying to change views of a rails application but changes don't apply

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view

I am trying to change the html.erb files from my application, but when i upload the new version and i check with a browser it's still the old one, i tried different browsers/cleared cache.

Do I need to restart the app? if so, how do i do that?

Comment: Possible causes are the html files are getting stuck in the project's public directory (unless you're uploading the whole application again each time), or in a cache somewhere. As a quick test, run "locate foo.html" or "find / -name foo.html" on the server to check if there are artifacts somewhere.

Comment: You "upload" the file? Why are you not running locally in dev mode. If you are running in production, things are likely being cached on the server end.

Comment: What version of RoR are you using? if 3.1> then you may have to recompile your assets `rake assets:precompile`

Comment: For future reference, please provide your framework version, environment (whether local, or server), and what your server environment is (e.g. Heroku, EngineYard, etc). The more information you can provide the better and quicker your answer will be!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you are "uploading the new version" which suggests that you're talking about a server run in production mode (e.g. not your local development environment).  In that case, yes, you likely need to restart your application server.  E.g. if you are running with Apache/Passenger, then restart Apache.